# How can I coherently use a sentence to effect of "entrusted by both Client and Project Management"

Tags: american-english, british-english, writing

I am putting strenuous effort however it sounds garbled.

> For a role way over my head, *I was entrusted both by Client and Project manager with full oversight and control of site activities* as I had done a similar project earlier exceeding expectations and promoted. Yet I cannot use a professional business language to word this in my CV.

Please help. I am open to any other suggestions!

Comment: We don't really do "proofreading" here, but if you can elaborate on what is giving you trouble it would be better.  Maybe add a few alternates that you also think are "garbled", and explain what you think is wrong with them?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrew. I had no intention of getting a proofreading. Rather I was confused how to use such sentence in a concise and potent way it goes to my CV. The question itself only an attempt to articulate what I am struggling. Between keeping it short and use of passive as it is the case for resume, I simply failed and sought out help.

Comment: I know, it's just that the rules for this site can be a little strict.  We appreciate when you make the effort to explain in detail what you've already tried to solve the problem, or if your question can be made more general so that it might help other people in the future.

Comment: And grammar issues aside, would you really want to put such a long sentence and description on your CV? Especially one that starts with "the role was way over my head"? I get what you're trying to express, but perhaps it's better left said in person, instead of on paper.

Comment: Perhaps the italic part is not visible on site? I only meant to use italic part followed by role descriptions. Over my head is, indeed, not the kind of expression I would want to include in a resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence itself is a bit convoluted. Suggest you string the ideas in a more linear way, but above all AVOID THE PASSIVE, which adds unnecessary complication, and makes you sound a less direct -- and employers like direct! I would suggest something like...

"Although the role was way over my head, both Client and Project Manager entrusted me with full oversight of site activities as I had exceeded expectations with an earlier similar project, which led to my promotion."

Even better, keep the sentences short...

"Although the role was way over my head, both Client and Project Manager entrusted me with full oversight of site activities. I had exceeded expectations with an earlier similar project, which led to my promotion."

("... which led to my promotion" -- the hanging "and promoted" at the end doesn't make much sense, and I'm not sure I have read the correct meaning into it.)

This query illustrates two major themes of good writing -- avoid the passive wherever possible, and the KISS principle ("Keep it simple, Stupid!" -- things always work better if kept as simple as possible) formulated by the US Navy in the 1960's.

Comment: Thank you Warren for suggestions and bonus information with KISS principle. Something I will clearly need to keep in mind. 

I did not mean to use whole sentence but only the italic part. In order to convey a message that not only project manager promoted me but also but also the Client requested me to supervise the project in a shortest way. For resume I need to use passive voice and from what you wrote "entrusted by both C&PM with oversight of site activities" is grammatically correct and fits into KISS rule?